MS Defender for Identity API query for "IdentityLogonEvents" table
I have a number of scripts that query various tables relating to device information in Defender for Endpoint ( DeviceProcessEvents , DeviceEvents etc ) . If i try and query the Identity ( IdentityLogonEvents) related tables i keep getting 402 errors ( bad requests ) .
I have searched for hours and i am strill struggling to understand if i have done something wrong or if its just not possible.
So i guess my question here has anyone actually managed to query the Identity related tables via the API ?
